# Origin of Dhanvantari's maha mantra and moola mantra

Tags: scripture, mantras, resource

Request you to let me know in which book can I find the Dhanvantri moola mantra and Maha Mantra. Also kindly mention the correct wording in Sanskrit of both the mantras.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I hope the question is fine. Please let me know any changes required. Thank you.

Comment: A downloadable link is not possible. We can only show you an online or off line resource if possible. Download etc., are subjected to copyright.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Please note that question is changed. I don't need download link.

Comment: Can anyone please answer my questions? I am new here

Answer (score 2):

Both the correct words and the mantra is mentioned in following sources.

- [National Institute of Indian Medical Heritage (NIIMH) - ebook](http://niimh.nic.in/ebooks/e-Nighantu/dhanvantarinighantu/?mod=read)
- [Indian National Science Academy Journal](https://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJHS/Vol05_2_13_PVSharma.pdf)

It is called **Dhanvantari Nighantu**, that's all I could find in my own search for the correct mantra, which also led me to this question.

**Edit:** As I searched further about Moola Mantras this is what I found. For ex.

1. For Lord Ganesh it is: **ॐ श्री ह्री क्लीं ग्लौं गं गणपतये वर वरद सर्वजनं मे वशमानय स्वाहा ।**
2. For Lord Hanuman it is: **ॐ ह्रां ह्रीं ह्रूं ह्रैं ह्रौं ह्रः ॐ॥**
3. But for Lord Dhanvantari I couldn't find one. If you find one kindly tell me as well.

   This should be the Mahamantra:

   **ॐ नमो भगवते महासुदर्शनाय वासुदेवाय धन्वंतराये:**

   **अमृतकलश हस्ताय सर्वभय विनाशाय सर्वरोगनिवारणाय**

   **त्रिलोकपथाय त्रिलोकनाथाय श्री महाविष्णुस्वरूप**

   **श्री धन्वंतरी स्वरूप श्री श्री श्री औषधचक्र नारायणाय नम: ||**

The One that I recite & have memorized is: ([Pronunciation: YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXd9K9LKKNM))

**नमामि धन्वन्तरिमादिदेवं सुरासुरैर्वन्दित पादपद्मं लोके जरारुग्भयमृत्युनाशं धातारमीशं विविधौषधीनाम्**

> Be mindful of these mistakes in her pronunciation: She misspelled only
>   one part (जरारुग्भयमृत्युनाशं)
>
> She says  (Jaraa ***ROUD*** bhay ***MRITYUR*** naasham)
>
> When it is (Jaraa ***ROUG*** bhay ***MRITYU*** naasham)

See this link for 3 or 4 more mantras https://indiaplus.co.in/sri-dhanvantri-mantra/

Let me know if you need any more help :)

Also please forgive my editing I tried to make it as readable as I could :D

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! I've just edited your answer to look it better. Use [proper formatting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help). It would be more useful if you add the text of Mantra with proper transliteration as asked in the question.

Comment: @James Thanks for the answer, but i can't find Dhanvantri moola mantra and Maha Mantra